# Global variables in Interface vs Singleton

Tags: java, interface, singleton, global-variables

I need to have couple global variables (eg: database name) which will be used by some other classes across my program.

I can create a Singleton class with the variables inside, but what I have found is that I can simply create an interface with the variables (without any methods) as well. As the variables in interface are static and final this seems to be a clean implementation.

I read thought that declaring variables in interfaces are poor design, so why is that and what is the best way to create global variables?

Comment: Opinion based, Both do the same crap,  Just different look :)

Comment: Opinion: Don't do global state no matter what needless complexity you hide your nasty surprise in.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline alright, but how should I store global stuff then? I guess it makes sense to have my database name coded at one place only instead of in every class which will use the db.

Comment: Use constructors. You wont need the database name in every class, because you'll be at least passing a database connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an interface only to hold constants is a code smell, according to [Sonar rule](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/d3eb9295131104fcda5871f919fd905534b15417/java-checks/src/main/resources/org/sonar/l10n/java/rules/squid/S1214_java.html):

`Constants should not be defined in interfaces (squid:S1214)`

> According to Joshua Bloch, author of "Effective Java":
> The constant interface pattern is a poor use of interfaces.
>
> That a class uses some constants internally is an implementation detail.
>
> Implementing a constant interface causes this implementation detail to leak into the class's exported API. It is of no consequence to the users of a class that the class implements a constant interface. In fact, it may even confuse them. Worse, it represents a commitment: if in a future release the class is modified so that it no longer needs to use the constants, it still must implement the interface to ensure binary compatibility. If a nonfinal class implements a constant interface,
>
> all of its subclasses will have their namespaces polluted by the constants in the interface.